# How to conduct in-sample forecasting?

Tags: forecasting

Whilst this may be a fundamental and basic question, I need to pin down a solid understanding of exactly *what* in-sample forecasting is and entails. I understand out-of-sample as taking a period of training data and forecasting future values based on the regression of data from that period. However, in-sample seems to be seldom defined without reference to not being out-of-sample.

Take the example of a time series from 1900-2000 for which I have a regression specification. I want to make in-sample forecasts for 1990-2000. What does this entail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entails using all the data available at your disposal, 100 years in this case, and fitting a model. Then you take the last year, say 1999, and make predictions for it using your model (which was fitted using all the data, including those of year 1999).

Basically, I don't know if anyone uses the name "in-sample prediction", but it corresponds to the bad practice of training a model with your data, and then "predicting" for a portion of that data.